# UPDATE on different tables and columns by similar condition

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have to run a procedure which will update an old value with the new value across several tables. All those tables are different and have different column name, and also they could not even have matching `$old_value` in them (in this case columns should not be updated), so only thing I could think of is to run a transaction, like this:

```
$new_value = 'something';

$DBH->prepare("SELECT old_value FROM table_0 WHERE id = :id");
$DBH->execute(':id' => $some_value);
$result = $DBH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if( $new_value != $result[0]['old_value'] )
{
    $DBH->beginTransaction();

    $DBH->exec("UPDATE table_1 SET column_1 = $new_value WHERE column_1 = $old_value");
    $DBH->exec("UPDATE table_2 SET column_2 = $new_value WHERE column_2 = $old_value");
    $DBH->exec("UPDATE table_2 SET column_3 = $new_value WHERE column_3 = $old_value");

    $DBH->rollBack();
}
```

Is there any better solution? Maybe way to run UPDATE on SELECT without affecting whole result set?

Comment: You're using placeholders in your `SELECT`, which is great, but you're using string interpolation on the `UPDATE` queries, which is extremely dangerous.

Comment: Yes, but there is no way `$old_value` could be a user input; this data comes from `session_id()` only; so I thought that prepared statement are not necessary in this case.

Comment: It's exceptions and excuses that get people into severe trouble. Use placeholders whenever possible. Stuff like this is an automatic fail of any SQL security audit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three different update conditions there, so you basically need three different updates. Enclosing them inside a transaction as you've done is the best way to do that reliably.

Comment: Thanks! I though so, but decided to ask anyway.

Comment: No harm in asking. Sometimes it's not clear if there really is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

At the end you need to do

```
$DBH->commit();
```

You do `$DBH->rollback()` only if you got an error. Rollback undos everything you have done since the start of the transaction.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include last line in the question `code block`, but that's not the point.